# Getting the max and the min paid departments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query :

```
 SELECT D.Dept,(SUM(D.AMOUNT) /SUM(A.AMOUNT)) AS Res 
FROM Dept AS D
INNER JOIN Charge AS A ON D.DeptId=A.DeptId
GROUP BY D.Dept
```

Input :
Dept table :

```
Dep Amount
1   300
1   300
2   1000
3   3000
```

Charge table :

```
Dep Charge
1   150
1   150
2   200
3   300
```

I want to calculate the sum of the amount of the salaries for each department and divide it by the charges of each department
I want to have the dept having the max and the dept having the min like below :

```
Dept  Res
3     10
2      5
1      2
```

To select the max and the min dept :

```
 Dept  Res
 3     10
 1      2
```

Comment: Sample data and tables in a consumable format would help considerably. You should also provide the expected output for your sample data.

Comment: You must SUM before joining - that is the essence of your problem.

Comment: In the simplest form, use one cte to sum from Dept, another to sum from Charge, then join and compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a CTE with 2 RANK ordered in opposite ways and then get the first in each direction to get the mini et maxi

> ```
> create table Dept (Dept int, Amount int);
> insert into dept values
> (1,   200),
> (1,   345),
> (2,   690),
> (3,   3000);
> create table Charge (Dept int, Amount int);
> insert into Charge values
> (1,   568),
> (1,   657),
> (2,   300),
> (3,   300);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   D.Dept,
>   SUM(D.AMOUNT) Salaries,
>   SUM(A.AMOUNT) Expenses,
>   round((1e* SUM(D.AMOUNT) /SUM(A.AMOUNT)),2) AS Res 
> FROM Dept AS D
> JOIN Charge AS A ON D.Dept=A.Dept
> GROUP BY D.Dept
> ORDER BY (1e* SUM(D.AMOUNT) /SUM(A.AMOUNT)) DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> Dept | Salaries | Expenses |  Res
> ---: | -------: | -------: | ---:
>    3 |     3000 |      300 |   10
>    2 |      690 |      300 |  2.3
>    1 |     1090 |     2450 | 0.44
> ```

> ```
> with allDepts as(
> SELECT 
>   D.Dept,
>   rank() over ( order by (1e* SUM(D.AMOUNT) /SUM(A.AMOUNT)) DESC) maxi,
>   rank() over (order by (1e* SUM(D.AMOUNT) /SUM(A.AMOUNT)) asc) mini,
>   round((1e* SUM(D.AMOUNT) /SUM(A.AMOUNT)),2) AS Res 
> FROM Dept AS D
> JOIN Charge AS A ON D.Dept=A.Dept
> GROUP BY D.Dept
> )
> select 
>   Dept, Res
> from allDepts
> where maxi = 1
> or mini = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> Dept |  Res
> ---: | ---:
>    1 | 0.44
>    3 |   10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb61b47bcbd46fcd2954aab553363c8e)*

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate and join each query as a derived table, derive the max and min values using a windowed aggregate, then filter:

```
with r as (
    select d.Dept, d.Amount / c.Amount Res, 
      Min(d.Amount / c.Amount) over() MinAmount,
      Max(d.Amount / c.Amount) over() MaxAmount
    from (
      select dept, Sum(Amount) Amount
      from Dept
      group by Dept
    )d join (
      select dept, Sum(Amount) Amount
      from Charge
      group by Dept
    ) c on c.Dept=d.Dept
)
select Dept, Res
from r
where Res in (MinAmount, MaxAmount);
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=899004edee3b07349776d92ddac72e40)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First aggregate both in sub-queries.
This gets a 1-on-1 relationship on the DeptId.
Then to get the MIN/MAX Res you can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK`.

> ```
> SELECT DeptId, Res
> FROM 
> (
>     SELECT D.DeptId, DeptAmount, ChargeAmount
>     , CAST(1.0*DeptAmount/NULLIF(ChargeAmount, 0) AS INT) AS Res
>     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1.0*DeptAmount/NULLIF(ChargeAmount, 0) ASC) AS RNK_ASC
>     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1.0*DeptAmount/NULLIF(ChargeAmount, 0) DESC) AS RNK_DESC
>     FROM (
>       SELECT DeptId, SUM(Amount) AS DeptAmount
>       FROM Dept
>       GROUP BY DeptId
>     ) D
>     INNER JOIN (
>       SELECT DeptId, SUM(Charge) AS ChargeAmount
>       FROM Charge
>       GROUP BY DeptId
>     ) C ON C.DeptId = D.DeptId
> ) Q
> WHERE (RNK_ASC = 1 OR RNK_DESC = 1)
> ORDER BY RNK_DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> DeptId | Res
> -----: | --:
>      3 |  10
>      1 |   2
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94b8d855cda9987281a0bf852cff6d9e)*